# Moving image on windows form

Tags: c#, image

Is it possible to make image, which is 'standing' still, move when I hover with my mouse over the image? I'm working in vs 2012, c# and win forms and I want simple movement like gif image, something similar to that, just to make it 'alive'

And how to make that? Thank you very much

Comment: What environment?  WPF?  WinForms?  Is the image in a control?  What kind of movement?  More detail, please.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, the title says Windows Form

Comment: @G.Stoynev And both WPF and WinForms produce a form on Windows, don't they.  Assume nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is - you can alter the Picturebox.Location like that. Note that this is an illustration and some edge cases may exist - for example you may want to add logic that detects when the image moved so much, that mouse went out (but within the original location)

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
    int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x + 25, y + 15);
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
    int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x - 25, y - 15);
}
```

Comment: This was great. There is litthe graphic element like a little bug depending on how fast you move your mouse over the icon but it's nothing much.Thanks